# How to calculate volume under $ f(x, y) $?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration

I have the following function:

```
σ = 0.3;
μ = 5;
cy =0;
cx=0;
f[x_,y_]=Exp[-(1/2)((Sqrt[(x-cx)^2+(y-cy)^2]-μ)/σ)^2]/(σ*Sqrt[2*π])
```

Plotting this with:

```
max=10;
Plot3D[f[x,y], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max,max}, PlotPoints -> {100, 100},PlotRange -> Full, ClippingStyle -> None, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000},Axes-> True,BoxRatios ->Automatic]
```

I get the following:
[image: Plot]

What I need is to calculate the volume below the entire function (Infinity) so I can use it as a normalization constant for using this function as a 2D PDF.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? I assume you tried `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`?

Comment: Is this the correct syntax: Integrate[f[x,y],{x,-Infinity,Infinity},{y,-Infinity,Infinity}]?
I get a value but I am not sure whether this is correct.

Comment: Yes, that is the syntax. Have you read the documentation page of `Integrate` (and that of `NIntegrate`) and looked at the many examples?

Comment: To verify, replace `Integrate` by `NIntegrate` and compare numerically. If `NIntegrate` complains, try subdividing the region like this : `NIntegrate[f[x,y],{x,-Infinity,-5,5,Infinity},{y,-Infinity,-5,5,Infinity}]`, where I picked ±5 from your graph.  You could also change to polar coordinates, which could be reduced to a single integral and and even be done by hand. Two or three distinct approaches that agree is pretty good evidence.

Comment: @Gouz The result from `Integrate` looks plausible. In your case of a normalization constant for a probability distribution Mathematicas automatic normalization does this conveniently for you: `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
  Exp[-(1/2) ((Sqrt[(x - cx)^2 + (y - 
               cy)^2] - \[Mu])/\[Sigma])^2]/(\[Sigma]*
     Sqrt[2*\[Pi]]), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, \
-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Method -> "Normalize", 
  Assumptions -> \[Mu] > 0 \[And] \[Sigma] > 0]` and is usable as a distribution (`PDF`, `CDF`, `RandomVariate`, etc. directly work).

Comment: Is this how I could sample from this dist?: "data=RandomVariate[dist, 1000]". I ask because this expression returns an error for me.

Comment: @Gouz You're right, i just double checked and Mathematica doesn't handle this distribution well, so in this case you are probably better off constructing the functions (normalized PDF, CDF and sampling, e.g. via InverseCDF) manually. If you want i can write something up as an answer to give examples how it can be done. Are you mainly interested in generating samples from this distribution or do you want to do something else?

Comment: No, thanx! I will not be generating samples. I just checked out of curiosity of how things work in Mathematica. I will be using different versions of the provided f[x,y] (i.e. different σ, μ, cy, cx) to generate and join different PDF's for positioning predictions in Java. I am trying to tackle a trilateration problem.

Comment: BTW.. I randomly chose σ=0.3 and μ=5 but I noticed that the integration of this function is approx Pi*10. Do you also find it weird :S? Is there any golden relationship between this σ and μ and the rotation of the function? :S

Answer (score 2):

This function is rotationally symmetric about `{cx,cy}` and hence polar coordinates might be a good idea. Indeed, the integral can be computed symbolically this way:

```
ClearAll[cx, cy, \[Sigma], \[Mu]];
f[x_, y_] = 
 Exp[-(1/2) ((Sqrt[(x - cx)^2 + (y - cy)^2] - \[Mu])/\[Sigma])^2]/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])
\[CapitalPhi] = {r, \[Theta]} \[Function] {cx + r Cos[\[Theta]], cy + r Sin[\[Theta]]};
g = Simplify[ f @@ \[CapitalPhi][r, q] Det[D[\[CapitalPhi][r, \[Theta]], {{r, \[Theta]}, 1}]]]
Integrate[g, {\[Theta], -Pi, Pi}, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

> `E^(-(\[Mu]^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) Sqrt[
>     2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma] + \[Pi] \[Mu] Sqrt[
>     1/\[Sigma]^2] \[Sigma] + \[Pi] \[Mu] Erf[\[Mu]/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])]`

Comment: For σ=0.3, μ=5, cx=0 and cy=0, the NIntegrate[
 f[x, y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}] returns 31.4159 (which btw surprised me since I picked these values by random and the outcome is aprox. pi*10) which is indeed the same as yours with the difference that yours, has also an imaginary part (i.e. 31.4159 - 1.07255*10^-12i). How to interpret this number?

Comment: On the other hand, the first way returns different values for different cx's and cy's which is also weird to me (shouldn't the integral be the same no matter the cx's and cy's?), while your approach indeed returns the same value nomatter the cx's and cy's. Which makes me feel a bit lost.

Comment: @Gouz with Henrik’s approach, we stay symbolic, and are not subject to the numerical error propagation present in uses of `NIntegrate` and other numeric functions.

Comment: @Gouz... looks like 10Pi ;-)

Comment: @mgamer Caution, this is only true because `Exp[-x^2/2]` falls off quickly with `x` while `Erf[x/Sqrt[x]]` converges quickly to `1` for $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. Yes, but the output of the computed integral (your code) is `10*Pi - 5 * GammaRegularized[-(1/2), 1250/9]` this is `10Pi -1.28589*10^-63`. For this specific mu and sigma, cx=cy=0.Not exactly 10 Pi but a good approximation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
In[2]:=
σ = 0.3;
μ = 5;
cy =0;
cx=0;
f[x_,y_]=Exp[-(1/2)((Sqrt[(x-cx)^2+(y-cy)^2]-μ)/σ)^2]/(σ*Sqrt[2*π])

 \!\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \
    \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \
    \(\[Infinity]\)]f[x, y] \[DifferentialD]x \[DifferentialD]y\)\)
Out[2]:31.4159
```

> $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty
>    }^{\infty }f(x,y)dxdy$

Comment: This is merely a formatted output. Did you mean to post this with more content? —As it is now, it does not answer the question posed by the OP.

Comment: I have revised the statement.